# Closing app from recents does not clear memory data

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I am running Instrumentation tests.
Part of my tests require that the app be closed from recents and check what happens when the app is reopened.

However, variables stored in memory prior to clearing the app from recents do not get reset after the app is reopened.

Why is that?

The variables are booleans stored strictly in memory

Comment: in manifest within application tag use this line   android:allowBackup="false"

Comment: I already have this tag set